# Ajax youtube upload

Tags: ajax, upload, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to implement resumable video upload to Youtube, 
as described here: [youtube resumable upload api](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads.html) .
But I am getting error: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads". 
Here is code:

```
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var url = "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";   
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Host", "uploads.gdata.youtube.com");
    http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "AuthSub token=\"yDXi4sfOb8RYWDIH....MEAxMzE0MzAzMDEy\"");
    http.setRequestHeader("GData-Version", 2);
    http.setRequestHeader("X-GData-Key", "key=DI39si4Tl....18OaRy");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", 0);
    http.setRequestHeader("Slug", "test.avi");
    http.send(null);
```

I would be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resumable upload and direct upload facilities are not supported from browsers -- in particular they violate [browser same origin policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You need to either use the [browser based uploading](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading.html) or proxy the uploads through your server.